# Using Blazor InputFile within a repeating component - OnChange seemingly unable to track which component it's come from

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm having some issues with Blazor InputFile when using it within a repeating component, specifically getting the OnChange event to call the method in the correct instance of the repeating component.

Here's some code I've put together to demonstrate what I mean (I'm using Radzen components also):

The top level page razor component:

```
@page "/testing"

@foreach (var id in testingRepeaterIds)
{
    <TestingRepeater ComponentId="id"></TestingRepeater>
}

@code {
    private List<int> testingRepeaterIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

The `TestingRepeater` component:

```
<TestUpload OnChange="@((args) => LinkFilesToComponent(args.Item1, args.Item2))" EntityId="@ComponentId" />

<RadzenDataGrid @ref="attachmentGrid" AllowSorting="true" PagerHorizontalAlign="HorizontalAlign.Left" ColumnWidth="140px"
                Data="@attachedFiles" TItem="AttachmentDto"
                LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.Or" Responsive="true">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="AttachmentDto" Property="Attachment.FileName" Title="Name">
            <Template Context="attachment">
                <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="attachment.AttachmentName" class="w-100" />
            </Template>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>


@code {
    [Parameter] public int ComponentId { get; set; }

    private RadzenDataGrid<AttachmentDto> attachmentGrid;

    private List<AttachmentDto> attachedFiles = new List<AttachmentDto>();

    private async void LinkFilesToComponent(List<AttachmentDto> files, int entityId)
    {
        if (entityId == ComponentId)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                attachedFiles.Add(file);
            }

            attachmentGrid.Reload();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `TestUpload` component which contains the built in Blazor InputFile component:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <InputFile @key=@(_inputFileId) OnChange=@LoadFiles accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
               style="width: 0px;" multiple class="custom-file-input d-none" id="inputGroupFile" />
    <label class="rz-button rz-button-md rz-variant-flat rz-dark rz-shade-dark" for="inputGroupFile">Choose File(s)</label>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<AttachmentDto>> OnChange { get; set; }

    private List<AttachmentDto> loadedFiles = new();
    private bool isLoading;
    private string _inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        isLoading = true;

        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())
        {
            var uploadedFile = new AttachmentDto
                {
                    DiskName = Path.Combine("uploads", file.Name),
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    FileSize = file.Size,
                    FileType = file.ContentType,
                };

            loadedFiles.Add(uploadedFile);
        }

        await OnChange.InvokeAsync(loadedFiles);

        isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

My object `AttachmentDto` looks like this:

```
public class AttachmentDto
{
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string DiskName { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm finding is that whichever repeater button I use to upload the files, they always get uploaded to the table of the first component, like in the screenshot below. I thought that providing a `@key` against the `InputFile` component would help Blazor track which component I was trying to work with, but this doesn't seem to help here. I've also tried passing through the `ComponentId` as a parameter to the `TestUpload` component so that I can then pass it back with the files, but although it seems to have the correct Id at the point of initialising, it's always then the wrong Id by the time `LoadFiles` is called.

[image: screenshot of blazor repeater component with inputfile]

For context, I'm using .net 8 and Blazor Web App, though my Routes component is set to use InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false) so I think it's essentially like working with Blazor Server.

Comment: Note that this code won't compile. It looks like it's stitched together from different versions. Please don't do that, see [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @key won't help much in this case.

But you have an `id` that is the same in all 3 instances. So pass the ComponentId down to the TestUpload component and use it instead:

From

```
   <InputFile @key=@(_inputFileId) OnChange=@LoadFiles accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"
     id="inputGroupFile" />
   <label for="inputGroupFile">Choose File(s)</label>
```

To

```
   <InputFile @key=@(_inputFileId) OnChange=@LoadFiles accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg"  
    id="@ComponentId" />
   <label for="@ComponentId">Choose File(s)</label>
```

I left out the class= for clarity.